# React Native: how can I achieve the dynamic keys with multiple objects

Tags: react-native

Here is my code I tried,

```js
var array=[];
var list = this.state.list;

var getList = function(i){
  var add = +i + 1;
  return {
    ["value"+add]:{
      Description:list[i].Description,
      Length:list[i].Length,
      Height:list[i].Height,
      Weight:list[i].Weight,
      VolumeWeight:list[i].VolumeWeight,
      ActualWeight:list[i].ActualWeight,
    }
  }
}.bind(this)

for(var i in list){
  array.push(getList(i));
}

var dataArray = array.map(function(e){
  return JSON.stringify(e);
});

dataString = dataArray.join(",");
data1 = {
  ConsigneeBranchName:this.state.searchText,
  ConsigneeBranchCode:this.state.code,
  ConsigneeBranchFullAddress:this.state.DAddress,
  SenderBranchCode:this.state.code1,
  SenderBranchName:this.state.searchTexts,
  SenderBranchFullAddress:this.state.Address,
  CreatedByEmployeeCode:id,
  CreatedByEmployeeFullName:userName,
  jsonString:{
    JsonValues:{
      id:"MyID",
      values:dataString
    }
  }
}
```

But I want the result is exactly this

```js
var result = {
  "ConsigneeBranchName":"",
  "ConsigneeBranchCode":"",
  "ConsigneeBranchFullAddress":"",
  "SenderBranchCode":"",
  "SenderBranchName":"",
  "SenderBranchFullAddress":"",
  "CreatedByEmployeeCode":"",
  "CreatedByEmployeeFullName":"",
  "jsonString":"{
    "JsonValues": {
      "id": "MyID",
      "values": {
        "value1":{
          "Description”:"testSmarter1",
          "Length”:"60",
          "Height”:"50",
          "Weight”:"70",
          "VolumeWeight”:"75",
          "ActualWeight”:”78"
        },
        "value2:{
          "Description":"Documents",
          "Length":"120",
          "Height":"68",
          "Weight":"75",
          "VolumeWeight":"122.4",
          "ActualWeight":"123"
        },
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Please any one help me**

I want the object with dynamic keys within a single object {key1:{des:1,value:as},key2:{des:2,value:aw},key3:{des:3,value:au}}

can you please help me I have tried so many times

see this below image I want this part, inside the single object, I can join multiple objects with dynamic keys

Comment: Are you trying to convert an array of objects to an object with key value pair. For example

`
   [{name: 'Jenitha', reputation: 6}, {name: 'Chandan', reputation: 3}]
`

To this format

`
{
  jenitha: { name: 'Jenitha', reputation: 6 },
  chandan: { name: 'Chandan', reputation: 3 }
}
`

Comment: yes I want this format. can you please show the sample

Comment: Check the answer and let me know if it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

lodash already has a function called **keyBy**, you can use it to get this functionality. If adding lodash doesn't make sense in your project.

I have implemented a vanilla JS version.

```
function keyBy(array, mapperFn) {
    const resultObj = {};
    array.map(item => resultObj[mapperFn(item)] = item);
    return resultObj;
}

function arrayToObject (array, keyName = 'id') {
    return keyBy(array, function(element) {return element[keyName]});
}
```

**API:**

```
arrayToObject(targetArray, stringNameOfThePorpertyYouWantToUseAsKey);
```

**USAGE:**

```
const listOfUsers = [{name: 'Jenitha', reputation: 6}, {name: 'Chandan', reputation: 3}];
const mapOfUsersByName = arrayToObject(listOfUsers, 'name');
```

Comment: this is not working in my case. because I want the key with dynamic names like value1, value2, value3.....but that name(value) is not included in the array list{description:'',id:'',name:''}.                                                                                        I want the exact result is {value1:{des:'',id:'',name:''},value2:{des:'',id:'',name:''},value3:{des:'',id:'',name:''}}

Comment: I just solved my issue using.                                                                         object = Object.assign({}, ...array);

Comment: Thats a much neater solution :). But how did you create the custom keys?